# How do I add the trash icon to the desktop in Ubuntu 12.04 using Gnome3?

Tags: gnome, macosx

So I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.1 on my iMac G5 powerpc64 and I want to add the trash icon to the desktop. How do I do that?

Please note, I am NOT using Unity.

I tried hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> and typing `gconf-editor` but it says that there is no such file or directory.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I found out that gconf-editor for Gnome3 is actually called Advanced Settings.
I searched for it in the Software Center and installed it and ran it afterwards from System Tools-Preferences-Advanced Settings

Everything I needed to adjust was inside this program.